# Conditionally replace first character (or first two) of a column with value from that row's other column (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe such as the following:

```
ID country region

1 32         32001
2 32          1001
3 68         68001
4 214        19017
5 214       214017
```

All variables are character, despite being integers.

I am cleaning the data and need all of the `region` variable to be the same. However, due to a clerical error in the dataset, some observations randomly switch from beginning the `region` code with the `country` code as the first two digits to using ascending numbers 1-19 (Countries 1-19). I therefore want to replace the first digit of `region` for all these **incorrectly-coded** cases (where `region` > 1000 & < 10000) with that row's country code, for regions starting with numbers 1-9. Then, for all **incorrectly-coded** regions (where `region` > 10000 & < 20000) starting 10-19, I want to replace the first **two** digits of all these observations with that row's country code. All other observations would be left the same. The desired output would be the following:

```
ID Country Region

1 32         32001
2 32         32001
3 68         68001
4 214       214017
5 214       214017
```

The maximum value of these **incorrectly** coded regions is **19027** and the minimum value of the **correctly** coded regions is **32001**, so there would be no overlap to do this algorithmically. The only point would be to make sure that regions with a value greater than 9999 have their first two digits replaced, not just the first digit. Is there a way to do this succinctly, rather than manually recoding these all?

Comment: Can you provide part of the data that contains the problematic rows (some of the proper format and some with the error)?

Comment: Yes, that is provided in the first example. Rows 1, 3 and 5 are proper. Rows 2 and 4 are problematic.

Comment: What I mean is not a photo but what has been provided by the two answers below

Comment: there is very likely a better, easier and safer way to solve this upstream, if we can change the way this "clerical error" occurs. As is, this looks like an xy problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a one-liner in base R:

```r
transform(df, region = paste0(country, substr(region, nchar(region) - 2, 9)))
#>   ID country region
#> 1  1      32  32001
#> 2  2      32  32001
#> 3  3      68  68001
#> 4  4     214 214017
#> 5  5     214 214017
```

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), country = c("32", 
"32", "68", "214", "214"), region = c("32001", "1001", "68001", 
"19017", "214017")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df
#>   ID country region
#> 1  1      32  32001
#> 2  2      32   1001
#> 3  3      68  68001
#> 4  4     214  19017
#> 5  5     214 214017
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(region = str_replace(region, ".*(...)$", str_c(country, "\\1")))
```

-output

```
  ID country region
1  1      32  32001
2  2      32  32001
3  3      68  68001
4  4     214 214017
5  5     214 214017
```